# Are “Xylofon” and “xenophob” really pronounced with /ks/?

Tags: pronunciation

Pronunciation dictionaries suggest that words beginning with *x*, such as *Xylofon* and *xenophob*, should be pronounced with /ks/. This sounds awkward every time I try.

How common is it for real-life dialects to change this sound to something easier? If I talked about *Xenongas*, pronounced /se:nɔngas/, would I be understood?

Comment: 40 minutes' silence, and then three answers within a minute of each other. Did a German TV show just end? Thanks for the answers, there seems to be no disagreement.

Comment: I don't agree, I think it's rather pronounced gs, not ks.

Comment: No, it is not. Ks is the correct way. You are alone here with your opinion, maybe you want to provide some source for it?

Comment: At least in Austrian dialects, [ks] is often replaced with [gs]. Similar in parts of southern Germany.

Comment: Personally, although I might be influenced by English, I believe I would understand `xenophob, Xylophon, Xenosaga, Xanadu` pronounced with s. On the other hand, if you were to pronounce `Axt, hex (base 16), faxen, hexen, Vertex` as `Ast, hess, fassen, Hessen, Vertes (=werde es?)` I would be pretty confused.

Comment: markus and painfulenglish are right: In Austria, at the beginning of a word the letter »x« is pronounces more like [gs] than [ks]. This is not only true for dialects, but also for Standard German. Xylophon = [gsülofon], Xaver = [gsafa], Xenon = [gsenon]. In the middle or the end of a word it is [ks]: Taxi = [taksi], Felix = [feliks], Axt = [akst]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Definitely we Germans pronounce those *X*’s as /ks/.

And I doubt, that I understand /se:nɔngas/ immediately.

But after a short time I would learn to understand your way to pronounce this character. Though I think it depends on your audience. 
I don’t think it would be a great handicap in technical business talk (compared to knowing the vocabulary you are using).

Comment: +1, the comment on technical business talk reminds me of [C Pound](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/5_years_C-pound_experience.aspx).

Answer (score 13):

I think I never heard a different pronunciation. It's correct, yes. After all, the letter x in itself is pronounced like *iks* (or *ikks*). Listen, for example, to the samples on dict.cc; at least for [Xylophon](http://www.dict.cc/?s=xylophon), there's a real entry (xenophob is computer-generated).

Many people might have problems understanding what you mean if you pronounce it with just /s/, depending on the rest of the word. Xylophon may be understood because it provides enough clue as a whole.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, they are really pronounced that way, and I cannot see anything awkward or difficult about it.

I don't know any dialect that avoids the proper pronunciation of *X*.

Of course, words like *Xenongas* and *xenophob* are rarely used in dialects, but on the other hand, words that start out with *Ges-* are commonly pronouced *Ks-* in many dialects:

> gesund pronouced: xund
>   Gesicht pronounced: xicht
>   Geschichte pronounced: kschicht

It is unlikely that you would be understood without context and it would be just wrong, like saying *k* instead of *kr*.

Comment: @Tim Note that I accept that it is difficult for you to pronounce it, but you used "awkward" and "something easier" in an objective general sense that I felt the need to counter here. You might want to inform us how you pronounce these words in your native language.

Comment: Sorry about the subjective terms. Interesting about _xund_, I had never heard of that.

Comment: This reminds me of a Swabian reponse to (repeated) sneezing, which is pronounced "Xundheit, Xaver, Xälzbrot!". It uses the Swabian peculiarity of pronouncing the start of the words "Gesundheit", "Xaver" (a name) and "Gesälzbrot"/"G'sälzbrot" (which in turn is dialect for "Marmeladenbrot", bread with jam) similarly.

Comment: I'm quite sure @Tim's native language is English. Most German speakers would be surprised to learn that the x in xenophobe, xenon, etc. is pronounced as [z] in English.

Comment: @painfulenglish Actually it's Swedish, and here there's some controversy about the pronunciation of words such as *xenophobia* and *psychology*.

Comment: @Tim Controversies within the Swedish language? Or regarding English words?

Comment: @painfulenglish about the Swedish pronunciation of the corresponding Swedish words, e.g. *xenofobi* and *psykologi*.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, *x* is pronounced [ks] in German regardless of its position in the word.

There is only one exception. If *x* means the letter X and is connected by a hyphen, e. g.

- X-Beine
- x-beliebig
- X-Chromosom
- x-förmig

In these cases the starting X is pronounced [ɪks].

Answer (score 6):

For what it’s worth, I *do* know Germans who also have difficulty pronouncing the *x* at the beginning of a word. I agree with the other answerers that just pronouncing /s/ would not be well understandable, but I think with a /ts/ instead you’d do OK: so you could think *Zylophon*.

But the best is of course to keep practising /ks/.

Answer (score 4):

Your examples are directly derived from ancient greek, where the corresponding letter Ξ was pronounced the same way and still is in modern Greek, if I may trust [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xi_(letter)). *X* is always pronounced /ks/ in German, no matter, where in the word, the *x-* special case directly linked to alphabet enumeration. You did not mention, why you mistrust the dictionaries, but in any case the English language with its readiness to leave out unusual combinations (compare pronounciation of *psychology*) is a bad measure of reference.

Answer (score 4):

I do not think that the 'ks' sound is perceived as difficult by German speakers. Remember that we also have lots of 'ts' (represented by 'z') and 'pf' sounds. (There is however an Appel/Apfel dialect line.)